# Unity C# execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, android-sdk, gradle

Я пытаюсь скомпилировать apk моей игры в unity 2022 lts, но получаю следующие ошибки, может у кого-то есть идеи как решить?

Заранее спасибо!

```
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-31\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-32\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:syncReleaseLibJars UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :unityLibrary:extractReleaseAnnotations
94 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 90 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

---

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$1 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$10 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$11 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$12 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$13 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$14 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$15 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$16 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$17 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$18 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$19 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$2 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$20 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$21 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$22 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$23 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$24 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$25 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$26 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$27 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$28 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$29 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$3 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$30 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$31 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$32 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$33 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$34 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$35 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$36 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$37 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$38 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$39 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$4 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$40 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$1 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$1$1 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$2 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$2$1 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$2$2 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$2$3 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$2$4 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$2$5 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$2$6 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$2$7 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$3 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$3$1 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$3$2 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$3$3 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$3$4 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$3$5 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$3$6 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$41$3$7 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$42 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$43 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$44 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$5 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$6 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$7 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$8 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge$9 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridgeConstants found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridgeUtilities found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayInterstitialWrapper found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayInterstitialWrapper$1 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayInterstitialWrapper$2 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayInterstitialWrapper$3 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayInterstitialWrapper$4 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayInterstitialWrapper$5 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayInterstitialWrapper$6 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayInterstitialWrapper$7 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayRewardedVideoWrapper found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayRewardedVideoWrapper$1 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayRewardedVideoWrapper$2 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayRewardedVideoWrapper$3 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayRewardedVideoWrapper$4 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayRewardedVideoWrapper$5 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayRewardedVideoWrapper$6 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayRewardedVideoWrapper$7 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayRewardedVideoWrapper$8 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.LevelPlayRewardedVideoWrapper$9 found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.UnityBannerListener found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.UnityImpressionDataListener found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.UnityInitializationListener found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.UnityInterstitialListener found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.UnityLevelPlayBannerListener found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.UnityLevelPlayInterstitialListener found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.UnityLevelPlayRewardedVideoListener found in modules IronSource-bridge (IronSource-bridge.jar) and android-bridge (android-bridge.jar)
     Duplicate class com.ironsource.unity.androidbridge.UnityLevelPlayRewardedVideoManualListener found in modules IronSource-bridg<message truncated>
```

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-duplicated-classes-when-building-for-android.857158/

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, нужно было лишь переимпортировать ironsource в проект.Всем спасибо!